# Postgres table with more rows or fewer rows with more data in each row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm in a situation where I need to track user information very similar to fitbit steps, and am looking for feedback on two thoughts I had on modelling the data.

My requirements are to store the number of samples on a minute by minute basis. These are also going to be associated to a user (who did the steps), challenges and tasks for the user to complete. (gamification)

Now I can store all the samples in one table

```
id(pk)  | user  | start date       | steps | challengeId
uuid1   | user1 | 1/1/2015 10:00PM | 100   | challenge1
uuid2   | user1 | 1/1/2015 10:01PM | 101   | challenge1
... can have hundreds of minutes with a challenge 
uuid3   | user1 | 1/1/2015 10:02PM | 102   |
uuid4   | user2 | 1/1/2015 10:00PM | 100   |
```

so user1 has 303 steps between 10:00PM and 10:02PM but was only participating in challenge1 at 10:00PM and 10:01 PM

However, I don't think this can scale, since assuming ideal data for a single user in a year

12 (hours in a day) * 60 (minutes in a day) * 365 (days in a year) = 262,800 records in a database, for 1 user.  Considering 100k users, the table would become pretty large.

I'm also thinking about the idea of grouping the minutes into a concept of a session, where it would look like

```
id(pk)  | user  | start date       | steps     | challengeId
uuid1   | user1 | 1/1/2015 10:00PM | [100,101] | challenge1
uuid2   | user1 | 1/1/2015 10:01PM | [102]     | 
uuid3   | user2 | 1/1/2015 10:02PM | [102]     |
```

where the steps array assumes an 1 minute intervals. based on the use cases, there could hundreds / thousands of minutes in a challenge.

I think the second approach makes sense, since it means querying single records vs hundreds or thousands and could shrink the table by a factor of hundreds, but if there are any gotchas to this approach or any thoughts, it would be appreciated.

Comment: 262800 rows in a table is nothing -  even ten times that number is not considered "huge". It does get "huge" if you consider 100k users indeed. But if you _always_ query the data per user, than partitioning the table per user should work out quite nicely

Comment: Hello Horse, yes, I'm always going to query by user (and usually by a date as well), which are individually indexed. When you mention partitioning by user, were you thinking partitioning by say, the month they signed up? Do you have any thoughts on starting simple (no partitioning) and then migrating to a partitioned db later? (a migration sounds like it might be a decent amount of work and possible db downtime)